# how smarty use cache in this case

Tags: caching, smarty

```
if(!$smarty->isCached("sidebar.tpl")){
$tags = $tagService->tagList();
$categories = $categoryService->categoryList();
$sidebarData = $smarty->createData();
$sidebarData->assign("tags", $tags);
$sidebarData->assign("categories", $categories);
$smarty->setCacheLifetime(3600*24);
$sidebarHtml = $smarty->fetch("sidebar.tpl", $sidebarData);
```

}

I want assign $sidebarHtml to another Template, bu it seems dosen't work, I can get $sidebarHtml, through:
 `$smarty->fetch("sidebar.tpl")`
I need $tags and $categories for 'sidebar.tpl'
or
 `$smarty->fetch("sidebar.tpl", $sidebarData);`
the $sidebarData is undefined

how to deal in this case

Answer (score 0):

This page:
 http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.is.cached.tpl

```
Shows this example:
<?php
$smarty->setCaching(Smarty::CACHING_LIFETIME_CURRENT);

if(!$smarty->isCached('index.tpl')) {
// do database calls, assign vars here
}

$smarty->display('index.tpl');
?>
```

So in your case you should put the fetch after the closing } of the iscached's if.

Comment: yes I know, but which method "display()" called need parameter $sidebarData,$sidebarData is in if(...)｛... ...｝